# Migration from react-redux to react-final-form

Tags: react-redux, react-admin, react-final-form

I updated my `react-admin` project to v3, some of the changes in this version update included migration from from `react-redux` to `react-final-form` and i'm trying to fix some bugs related to this change.

I'm probably not using `react-final-form` right- I used to use the `.change()` function which connected my changed input field values to the store.

I followed `react-final-form` docs, and tried changing it like this:

get the form:

```
const form = useForm()
```

then use it's `.change` method to update my UI :

```
form.change('isadmin', this.state.isAdmin)
```

but im getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

here's is how my AdminButton component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch'
import { showNotification, fetchStart, fetchEnd, refreshView } from 'react-admin'
import { httpClient } from '../../dataProvider'
import { getFormValues } from 'redux-form'
import { useForm } from 'react-final-form'

const AdminButtonStyle = {
  zIndex: 2,
  display: 'inline-block',
  float: 'right',
  color: 'black'
}

class AdminButton extends Component {
  state = {
    isAdmin: this.props.formStates && this.props.formStates.isadmin
  }

  handleClick = async () => {
    const form = useForm()
    const { fetchStart, fetchEnd, record, showNotification } = this.props
    this.setState({
      isAdmin: !this.state.isAdmin
    })
    fetchStart()
    try {
      await httpClient(
        `api/users/${record.id}`,
        { method: 'PATCH', body: JSON.stringify({ isadmin: !this.state.isAdmin }) })
      form.change('isadmin', this.state.isAdmin)
      showNotification(`toggled user admin: ${this.state.isAdmin}`, 'success', { autoHideDuration: 10000 })
    } catch (err) {
      showNotification(`Error: ${err.data || err.message}`, 'warning', { autoHideDuration: 10000 })
    } finally {
      fetchEnd()
    }
  }

  render () {
    return <div style={AdminButtonStyle}>
      <span>Make Admin</span>
      <Switch
        checked={this.state.isAdmin}
        variant='raised'
        color='primary'
        size='large'
        onClick={this.handleClick}>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    formStates: getFormValues('record-form')(state)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchStart,
  fetchEnd,
  showNotification,
  refreshView
})(AdminButton)
```

So can anyone help me understand what i'm doing wrong? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `useForm` or `useFormState` outside a `Form` context. That said, try to wrap your component inside a `Form` like

```js
import { SimpleForm } from 'react-admin';

<SimpleForm {...props}>
  ... // your component
</SimpleForm>
```

or use the `react-final-form` component directly

```js
import { Form } from 'react-final-form';

<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  {({ handleSubmit }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    ... // You component
    </form>
 )}
</Form>
```

Then in you component, you can use `useForm` hook like

```js
import {useForm} from 'react-final-form';

const AdminButton = () => {
  const form = useForm();
    
  const handleClick = async () => {
    ...
    form.change('isadmin', isAdmin);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me fix some of the bugs, but my question still remains - how would you use the change function? theres no such hook & my AdminButton is wrapped in react-admin's SimpleForm component

Comment: It seems you are using it right, I've updated my answer so.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a React hook inside of a Class component. That's not allowed. Try to convert your component to a functional component.